# Javascript Read Object Array

Tags: jquery, ajax, vue.js

I have jquery code from which I'm fetching the data report based on weekdays.
What I want is to read an array object returned by ajax. 
 Here is the script :

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            currentcohortgraphdata: [{"Monday":"0","Tuesday":"0","Wednesday":"0","Thursday":"0","Friday":"0","Saturday":"0","Sunday":"0"}],
        }
    },
    mounted() {

    },
    methods: {
        loadCohortAttendancies() {
            this.$Progress.start();
            axios.get("api/loadCohortAttendancies").then(({data}) => (this.currentcohortgraphdata = data));
            this.$Progress.finish();
            var result = this.currentcohortgraphdata;

            result.forEach(function (e) {
                if (e.Monday > 0) {
                    alert(e.Thursday);
                }
            });
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.loadCohortAttendancies();
    },
    mounted() {

    }
}
```

When I run above script from ajax request `axios.get("api/loadCohortAttendancies").then(({data}) => (this.currentcohortgraphdata = data));` The results returned from the request is `[{"Monday":"12","Tuesday":"10","Wednesday":"3","Thursday":"5","Friday":"4","Saturday":"1","Sunday":"9"}]` 
. But unfortunately when I run the script I dont get result from the `alert(e.Thursday);` part of the script, can anyone point where I'm getting wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that you are running your code before your request is done, and it results in running your forEach with default values

> currentcohortgraphdata:
>   [{"Monday":"0","Tuesday":"0","Wednesday":"0","Thursday":"0","Friday":"0","Saturday":"0","Sunday":"0"}],

Simply move ur code inside .then block

```
axios.get("api/loadCohortAttendancies").then(({data}) => {
     this.currentcohortgraphdata = data
     this.$Progress.finish();
     var result = this.currentcohortgraphdata;

     result.forEach(function (e) {
         if (e.Monday > 0) {
             alert(e.Thursday);
         }
     });
});
```

Alternatively, you can use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax:

```
methods: {
  async loadCohortAttendancies() {
    this.$Progress.start();
    const { data } = await axios.get("api/loadCohortAttendancies");
    this.currentcohortgraphdata = data;
    this.$Progress.finish();
    const result = this.currentcohortgraphdata;

    result.forEach(function (e) {
      if (e.Monday > 0) {
        alert(e.Thursday);
      }
    });
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript is asynchronous, your `result.forEach` is running before your axios request is done. You can fix this by simply moving that block of code that relies on `currentcohortgraphdata` being set, into another `.then()` block following the one that sets the data. Like so:

```
loadCohortAttendancies() {
  this.$Progress.start()
  axios.get("api/loadCohortAttendancies")
    .then({data} => this.currentcohortgraphdata = data)
    .then(() => {
      this.$Progress.finish();
      var result = this.currentcohortgraphdata

      result.forEach(e => {
        if (e.Monday > 0) {
          alert(e.Thursday)
        }
      })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute forEach, the `axios.get` request method has not been executed yet.

So, change your code and try it like this

```js
loadCohortAttendancies() {
  this.$Progress.start();
  axios.get("api/loadCohortAttendancies").then(({data}) => {
    this.currentcohortgraphdata = data;
    this.currentcohortgraphdata.forEach(function (e) {
      if (e.Monday > 0) {
        alert(e.Thursday);
      }
    });
    this.$Progress.finish();
  });
}
```